# Solution for missing std::wstring support in Android NDK?

Tags: android-ndk, wchar-t, wstring, stlport

I have a game which uses std::wstring as its basic string type in thousand of places as well as doing operations with wchar_t and its functions: wcsicmp() wcslen() vsprintf(), etc.

The problem is wstring is not supported in R5c (latest ndk at the time of this writting).

I can't change the code to use std::string because of internationalization and I would be breaking the game engine which is used by many games ...

Which options do I have?

**1 - Replace string and wstring with my own string classes**

This would give me better platform independency, but it is ridiculous to reimplement the wheel.
I've already started with a COW implementation of strings. I need it to be COW because I use them as keys in hash_maps. 
This is of course lots of work and error prone ... but it seems it is something I can do.

**2 - Try to fix the NDK recompiling the STLPort with my own implementations of the wide char string functions of the C standart library (wcslen, mbstowcs ... )**

This would be the preferable way ... but I have no idea how to do it :(

How do I replace a function (lets say wcslen) in the libstdc++.a or libstlport_static.a? (not sure where they are :()

And as well I'm not sure which functions I need to reimplement, I know wcslen is not working so I guess they should be all ...

**3 - Do you have any other idea?**

I can't wait for an official fix for this and I will have to go with option #1 if I can't realize how to do #2.

I've read somewhere that if you target 2.3 you can use wstrings, but I ought to target Android 2.1.

PS: Forgot to say I need to use STL of course, but no RTTI and I can live without exceptions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does setting `APP_STL := stlport_static` in your Application.mk not work? It compiles `std::wstring test = L"test";` for me. (Haven't tried running anything though.)

Comment: @Martin Stone
stlport compiles perfectly but
`std::wstring test = L"test";
assert( test.size() != 1 );  // fails!!!!!`
tracking it wsclen fails too, it returns 1 (I guess they are doing some casting to char* only) further investigation showed me that stl_port is using many functions (don't know how many nor which ones exactly) of the standard C library ...

Comment: Would it be an option to simply convert all your wstrings to strings (using `setlocale()` + `wcsrtombs()`) at well-defined interface points in your program? That way you can keep everything the way it is internally and only add a little bit of modification when you need to output strings.

Comment: Sorry,wcsrtombs doesn't work, but I can create my implementation of a converter to utf8 if it were the case (actually I have already coded that), the problem is I have std::wstring in more than 1500 places where it is used, and I would need to review each one if I modify its behaviour. So what I need is to find a replacement for the C wide character functions in the NDK and recompile the STL (something I have no idea how to do) ... or the other solution is to write my own std::wstring class which mimics the std behaviour, as I said above.

Comment: @user548569: I might have misunderstood your question. Are you claiming that your platform does not _have_ `wchar_t` (and `std::wstring`) so that you cannot even compile your code?

Comment: Worst than that ... wchar_t and std::wstring are defined with wrong implementations. So I need to either recompile the NDK stl or to change every place where I used wstring and wchar_t for a utf8 implementation or my own wchar_t/wstring implementation ... I don't know how to do the first option because it would be the desired way ...

Comment: Did you get a resolution to this?  I am still seeing in NDK R7 and CrystalX too does not have wcsicmp methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try out CrystaX's NDK.  It has had stl support long before the official google one.  The current version (r5), which is based off the of the official ndk r5, is still beta 3, but it does have wchar_t support.

http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r5.php

Comment: Please confirm that CrystaX NDK really has wcsicmp()?  I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suffering from the same problem as you, but my only other thought is to load the strings via the JNI (as `jstring*` in native land), then convert them to UTF characters as necessary. Take a look at the available JNI string functions here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#string_operations

Comment: How is this a solution for hundreds of std::wstring and wcsicmp uses?

Answer (score 0):

**Qt** provides an excellent copy-on-write, international-friendly [string implementation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstring.html), **QString**, that is LGPLed.

You could, in theory extract it from the Qt source and use it in your own project. You will find the QString implementation in `src/corelib/tools/qstring.h` and `.cpp` in a [Qt source download](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/). You would also need the `QChar`, `QByteArray`, `QAtomic`, and `QNamespace` includes/classes (all under the `corelib` folder,) and you should define `QT_NO_STL_WCHAR` when compiling. (For this I would compile by hand or using my own script/Makefile.) Not simple, but once you get it up and running your life will be a lot simpler. It's better than reinventing the wheel, because it comes with loads of convenience functions and features.

Rather than stripping out just QString, you could also just use the QtCore module as a whole. See the [android-lighthouse project](http://code.google.com/p/android-lighthouse/) for a Qt port to Android. (Also, it might be better to get your sources from there than from the above "vanilla" link, regardless of what you do.)

Comment: Thanks, I already gone with my own utf8 string implementation.

Comment: @user548569: Could you post your own implementation as an answer? It's OK to answer your own questions if you've figured out the best way!

Comment: How is changing thousands of places into Qt calls a good solution? There are plenty of i18n libraries to recommend, but that wasn't the question. (I love Qt, but this is simply an irrelevant answer.)