# Boost::Spirit compilation error

Tags: android, c++, boost-spirit

I rarely ask about compilation error but following kind of error puzzled me.

I successfully compiled boost libraries for Android and I am trying to use its Spirit library to build a parser. But when I tried to compile. I get following errors.

As for first error in endian.hpp, I guess I need to include its cpu type (Android) in the file. But I have no idea why I am getting the other errors. Any clue or hint will be appreciated.

```
> In file included from
> C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/support/detail/integer/endian.hpp:37,
>                  from C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/support/detail/endian.hpp:24,
>                  from C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/binary/binary.hpp:16,
>                  from C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/binary.hpp:14,
>                  from C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:18,
>                  from C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
>                  from D:/mywork/dev/eclWork/BoostTest/jni/ndkfoo.cpp:24:
> C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/detail/endian.hpp:74:3:
> error: #error The file boost/detail/endian.hpp needs to be set up for
> your CPU type. In file included from
> C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/directive.hpp:14,
>                  from C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:19,
>                  from C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
>                  from D:/mywork/dev/eclWork/BoostTest/jni/ndkfoo.cpp:24:
> C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/directive/as.hpp:128:
> error: 'wstring' is not a member of 'std'
> C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/directive/as.hpp:128:
> error: 'wstring' is not a member of 'std'
> C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/directive/as.hpp:128:
> error: template argument 2 is invalid In file included from
> C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/math/special_functions/fpclassify.hpp:20,
>                  from C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/support/detail/sign.hpp:22,
>                  from C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric/detail/real_impl.hpp:22,
>                  from C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric/real.hpp:21,
>                  from C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi/numeric.hpp:17,
>                  from C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:21,
>                  from C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
>                  from D:/mywork/dev/eclWork/BoostTest/jni/ndkfoo.cpp:24:
> C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/fp_traits.hpp:472:
> error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type
> 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE' 
> C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/fp_traits.hpp:
> In static member function 'static void
> boost::math::detail::fp_traits_non_native boost::math::detail::extended_double_precision>::get_bits(long double,
> uint32_t&)':
> C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/fp_traits.hpp:457:
> error: 'offset_' was not declared in this scope
> C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/fp_traits.hpp:
> In static member function 'static void
> boost::math::detail::fp_traits_non_native boost::math::detail::extended_double_precision>::set_bits(long
> double&, uint32_t)':
> C:/Progra~1/Android/android-ndk-r6b/sources/boost/boost/math/special_functions/detail/fp_traits.hpp:462:
> error: 'offset_' was not declared in this scope make: ***
> [/cygdrive/d/mywork/dev/eclWork/BoostTest/obj/local/armeabi/objs/ndkfoo/ndkfoo.o]
> Error 1
```

Comment: The best advice that can be given is to move away from Spirit. There are many other alternatives out there.

Comment: @JaredKrumsie Thanks. I am leaning towards that way. Do you have any suggestion for the other alternatives?

Comment: It really depends on how complex your problem is, there's no silver bullet to these things.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's a bit late but this can be easily fixed by adding -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN to the mix.

Comment: I upset a lot of the standard includes by adding this directive.

Comment: it is successful in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I recently modified my endian.hpp with the patch described here

https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android/commit/8e2a1811445c077bc42f9d241cf0546f707786f3

works great

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer to your question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385643/solution-for-missing-stdwstring-support-in-android-ndk) . It seems that Android simply does not support std::wstring. However, I think Spirit should still work (given CPU endianess is set) with `char` type only - did you try?

Comment: Good to know. No I haven't tried it yet but am going to do that at some point.  Thanks!